# Using an Electronic Drum Kit as a MIDI controller

Tags: midi

I am trying to set up my Roland TD9KX2 for use as a MIDI controller with Superior Drummer 2.0 to do some recording. As I understand it, I need a DAW (thinking of trying REAPER). What cable do I need to connect it all up? Do I need extra hardware on top of that? Like an M-Box, or a special sound card or anything?

Comment: Can you not just use the USB cable from the drums to your computer? I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send the MIDI messages from the drum kit to the computer you will need a MIDI interface. Also, since for playing drums live you want very low latency (sub 10ms), you will need a reasonably good audio interface (most soundcards intended for recording will come with [ASIO drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output) that allow working at low latencies).

[image: mbox]

The [Avid mbox](http://www.avid.com/US/products/Mbox/features) would be fine since it contains a combined MIDI and audio interface. There are plenty of similar options available from other manufacturers. In the picture above you can see the standard MIDI connectors - you will need something with these connectors on them. You will also need a standard MIDI cable to connect from the MIDI out of your TD9 to the MIDI in of your interface.

If you already have a good audio interface, you can simply buy a MIDI to USB interface. For example, the [Roland UM1-EX](http://www.roland.com/products/en/UM-1EX/) is a cheap and simple solution, and doesn't require you to purchase a MIDI cable since it contains a built-in one.

Comment: If you have trouble finding that UM1-EX, I might also recommend M-Audio's Uno (http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_au/Uno.html).  I have also had decent luck with *some* of the generic $3 adapters on Amazon.  The trouble is, you never know what chips will be in there, and some of them lag terribly, or have very small buffers in which some of the packets drop.  Best to get something brand-name for this task.

Comment: I also have an [EMU X-MIDI](http://www.emu.com/products/product.asp?category=610&subcategory=611&product=15188), which works just fine with my V-Drums but for some reason misses occasional note-offs from my Yamaha stage piano